# creating association between tutorials and categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have created a  tutorials section and categories section. now i want to create association between these two sections.i have added has_many in my tutorials model.
this is my tutorial models definition:

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tutorialcategories
```

I got an error "undefined method tutorial category" in show method.

this is my tutorialcategories controller's definition

```
class TutorialcategoriesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

  def show
    @tutorials=Tutorial.order("id ASC").all
    @category = Tutorialcategory.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: make sure you have belongs_to :tutorial in tutorial_category.rb

Comment: have added belongs_to :tutorial in tutorialcategory.rb but still its not working . getting this error   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Tutorialcategories#index